# Photo morphing software

Tags: video, photography, video-editing

I'm looking for a photo morphing software that I can use to obtain something like this:

https://www.youtube.com/shorts/1hMIEtGow6A

It's strange I cannot find one online and most of the questions here on Software Recommendations are unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used one in decades. But in reality, [there are a ton of them](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=best%20photo%20morph%20software%20free).

One problem is that they are cheap software, that says they are free but in reality cost around $30. So I have not tried any of them in years. And I am more "picky" on what I install on my computers now, so I do not try anymore. And I can not recommend any of them. :(

One option is using Blender, which is a reliable and robust software, and deforming the mesh. There are some tutorials on YouTube. Some really old, but [here is one with the current interface](https://youtu.be/MlXH2frG6uc?si=lRobNIXBe0KTxy7N).

But the dedicated ones are way, way easier and faster. The tutorial itself is 15 mins long and that can be done in 3.

Answer (score 0):

I use blender,it is free and powerful.

Comment: Thank you @wenchong. Do you have a guide that you can maybe link here in your reply?

Comment: Does Blender provides out-of-the-box solution or do you have to map the points on the face manually in order to archive the result?

Comment: @wenchong: Please provide steps, or we will have to remove this answer per our answer quality guidelines: https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality Thanks for your understanding and looking forward to learning from you how to morph with Blender!

Comment: Here has a tuto: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MlXH2frG6uc    or this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bz3hIWRhGtY

Comment: https://pctechtest.com/22-best-photo-editing-software

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/67337)